# What archtecture/framework can be used to build a machine learning web app?

Tags: web-apps, software-development, machine-learning

I plan to build a web application to show case the algorithms and implemented methods for our business partners. More concretely several departments implemented machine learning methods in Python and Java and now I would like to make these methods available for our partners and customers.

Some requirements are

- Uploading private, sensible, large data (up to 70GB) by user/partner
- using implemented algorithms in Java or Python on uploaded data and return readable results
- able to use meta tags to label data

There has been a attempt to use Meteor for this project but due to some hosting difficulties and questions on separation of back- and front end, and technology stack a new discussion arose. There has been suggestions that JHipster could be a good tool to create this web app.

My question therefore is what frameworks/platforms or technology stack have been proven to be reliable, efficient and effective to fulfill the requirements?